# Discussing about the interval of existence for a nonlinear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

Consider the following nonlinear system:
$\dot{x}_1=x_1^3x_2^2-\frac{x_1^7}{1+x_1^8}$,
$\dot{x}_2=-kx_2$, where $k>0$.

In domain $D=\{(x_1,x_2)|\|x_1\|\leq 1, \|x_2\|\leq X\}$, I guess that the interval of the existence for this nonlinear system is not $[0,\infty)$, but I am not sure. Please help me to prove if this claim is true.
Also, please help me to imply if this system demonstrates
fnite-time escape of trajectories to infinity.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the actual question is you want to answer and what you have tried so far? Do you want to find the value for $X$ such that the origin is asymptotically stable?

Comment: Please help me to answer this question

Comment: I want to ascertain whether the equilibrium point of this system is asymptotic  stable or finite escape time. In other words, can we find the value of $X$ such that in region $D$, the equilibrium point be asymptotic stable?

Comment: Should all solution that start in $D$ also remain in $D$ or is it only required that the initial state is in $D$?

And can you also add what you have tried yourself so far? Namely, this question looks like something that could be homework and this site is not intended to provide people the answers to their homework. However, if you show what you have tried so far I might be able to guide you to the right answer.

Comment: It is only required that the initial state be in $D$. I tried to find a Lyapunov function for this system, but so far I have not succeeded.